# TestNG No tests found. Nothing was run. TestNG with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to use testng in selenium and unfortunately my tests are not executing. This is my code

[image: My Code]

Comment: post text based code please

Comment: Share the error trace as well.

Comment: Please add the error as well in your question so that its easier to understand the problem.

Comment: How do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong with your set property method and you should mention the extension of the file.

Ex- chrome.exe

Comment: Done that. No solution

Comment: Please check with your TestNG Version> 7.6.1 is stable one.